# Icon-off/icon-on icons not working for notifications in ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

I am using ionic 1. below is the ionic info.

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3
```

My project having tabs. issues is tab 1 is working (icon with text) but tab 2 only showing text but not the icon.

**tab1 is working**

```
<ion-tab title="PRODUCT" icon-off="ion-ios-briefcase" icon-on="ion-ios-briefcase" href="#/tab/chart">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chart"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

**tab 2 not working**

```
<ion-tab title="PRODUCT BREADTH" icon-off="ion-ios-notifications" icon-on="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

See below image (PRODUCT BREADTH icon is missing):
[image]
Thanks in advance..